# grpc can't make libgpr.a lib on MacOSX

Tags: macos, grpc

I tried to compile grpc on mac, by this [instruction](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/INSTALL.md). But failed **make** here printing this error log:

> [AR]      Creating
>   /Users/luliang/Downloads/grpc-master/libs/opt/libgpr.a error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   unknown option character `n' in: -no_warning_for_no_symbols Usage:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] Usage:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
>   -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #]
>   [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#]
>   [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table ]
>   [-seg_addr_table_filename ] [-all_load]
>   [-noall_load] make: ***
>   [/Users/luliang/Downloads/grpc-master/libs/opt/libgpr.a] Error 1

This should be typical. I don't know why. How to solve this?

Comment: On my OS X version 10.11.5 and the current git clone from https://github.com/grpc/grpc the make succeeds (but gives some suspicious warnings like `... warning same member name (slice.o) in output file used for input files ... ` (from `libtool Apple Inc. version cctools-886`). At least `-no_warning_for_no_symbols` is a valid libtool option ... please provide more details ...

Comment: Hey @lulyion, what version of XCode are you using? The `-no_warning_for_no_symbols` option was added [back in February](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/5335) to the Makefile.

Comment: @jcanizales thanks for reminding the IDE version,  I'm currently using a little deprecated version on an old mac, I will try the newest XCode version later.

Comment: Yeah, I've run into something similar with the `nm` tool: the version that comes with XCode 6.4 would only accept single-character options, while the version bundled with XCode 7 accepts "human-readable" options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jcanizales suggest, the version that comes with XCode 6.4 would only accept single-character options, while the version bundled with XCode 7 accepts "human-readable" options.

So as the solution, it's to update the xcode toolchains.